# How to get rid of the pole?

Tags: complex-analysis

There is given a meromorphic function:
$$f:\mathbb{C}-\{1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$$

It has a pole of order $1$ at point $1$

Consider now a new function $g(s)=f(1+\frac{1}{4(s-1)})$

> Find a holomorphic function $A(s)$, such makes the function $g(s)\cdot A(s)$ holomorphic

I tried multiply $g(s)$ by $(s-1)$ but i think it is not enough.

Regards

Comment: $A(s) \equiv 0$. If $f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$, that's the only one that works.

Comment: $A$ should be independent of $f$ (and $g$)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that $g$ has only a removable singularity at $s=1$.

For example, if $f(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}$, then $g(s)=4(s-1)$

I'm not sure how to prove if there will always be a removable singularity

Comment: No, not always, take $f(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+s$, then $g(s)$ has a pole in $1$